# access object of array of pointers from another class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is part of a larger project.

Basically I have a class "X" to manage the program and that class has an array of pointers to objects from a class "Y" and there are another class "Z" where I need to access the objects of the class "Y", for example a print.

I am getting the error "was not declared on this scope"

I tried to make the class "Z" friend of the class "Y" but it's not working.

I wrote code to demonstrate this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseClass;
class OtherClass;
class Manager;

class BaseClass
{
    friend class OtherClass;

    public:
        BaseClass(){}
        void setNum(int num){_num = num;}
        int getNum(){return _num;}

    private:
        int _num;
};

class OtherClass
{
    public:
        OtherClass(){}
        void print(){
        cout << _bc[0]->getNum() << " " << _bc[1]->getNum() << endl;
        }
};

class Manager
{
    friend class OtherClass;
    public:
        Manager(){}

        void run(){
            _bc = new BaseClass*[10];

            _bc[0]->setNum(20);
            _bc[1]->setNum(30);

           _oc.print();
        }

    private:
        BaseClass ** _bc;
        OtherClass _oc;
};


int main()
{
    Manager m;
    m.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this is very simple but it's late here, i'm sleepy and I want to solve this problem before go to bed.

EDITED:
In my project I have a class Manager and that class have array of pointers to **clients** and **orders**.
The class **orders** receive among other things a **client**, that's why I have to access that array of pointers, to choose what **client** to insert in the **order**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ there are two distinct concepts - *accessibility* and *scope*. From your question it appears that you've got these two concepts somewhat mixed up (I do not blame you, because they are very close to each other).

Accessibility is controlled by `private`, `public`, `protected` and so on, and can be additionally granted through "friendship". Scope, on the other hand, is controlled by the placement of the variables and functions being accessed.

In order for a member of a class to access a member of another class that other member must be in scope; it also must be accessible. It appears that you are attempting to access `_bc` from `OtherClass`, a `friend` of the class where `_bc` is declared. Friendship solves the accessibility part of the problem, but it does not address the scope part. In order for `OtherClass` to access `_bc`, an *instance* member of the `Manager` class, it must have a reference of some sort to a `Manager` object. There are many ways to get a reference - for example, you can pass a *reference* to the `Manager` in the constructor of `OtherClass`, store it in a private variable, and access `_bc` through it, like this:

```
class OtherClass {
    Manager &_m;
public:
    OtherClass(Manager &m) : _m(m) {}
    void print(){
        cout << _m._bc[0]->getNum() << " " << _m._bc[1]->getNum() << endl;
    }
};
```

This is only one way to solve the problem of scope; other ways include passing `Manager` as a parameter of `OtherClass::print`, making `_m` a pointer, making `_bc` static, and so on. The exact way depends on your requirements.

Comment: @wormwood87 You are welcome! If one of the answers on the page looks right, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to it, to tell others that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer.

Comment: My problem is not solved yet but now I understand why I have this problem, so it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not seem to need pointer to pointer types for `_bc`. Simply define an array in class `OtherClass` (or an `std::vector` is actually better) and make `Manager` a `friend` of `OtherClass`. And of course you can remove the `friend` declaration from the `BaseClass` and the `Manager` classes:

```
class OtherClass
{
  public:
    OtherClass(){}
    void print(){
      cout << _bc[0].getNum() << " " << _bc[1].getNum() << endl;
    }   
  private:
    BaseClass * _bc;
  friend class Manager;
};

class Manager
{
  public:
  Manager(){}

  void run(){
    _oc._bc = new BaseClass[10];
    _oc._bc[0].setNum(20);
    _oc._bc[1].setNum(30);

    _oc.print();
  }

  private:
  OtherClass _oc;
};
```

Comment: The problem of scope makes the `friend` statement impossible to use when you have each class in its own header file. So for this example, `friend class Manager` will always give a compiling error because the `Manager` header file has declared the `OtherClass` header file but not the other way around, meaning `OtherClass` has no knowledge of the `Manager` class!

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not function even if it compiled, as you did not correctly allocate the BaseClass instances. In addition, your use of raw `new[]` is extremely concerning. Consider using a `std::vector<BaseClass>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>>` instead.

In your OtherClass, you will have to take a Manager pointer or reference and delay the definition of it's print() member. The compiler is entirely correct in telling you that `OtherClass::print` has nothing called `_bc` in scope. You must explicitly pass the `Manager` instance.

Comment: I know it doesn't compile  that why I said "I am getting the error "was not declared on this scope"". I'll try that tomorrow, now i'm almost sleeping in my laptop.